# Is it possible to promisify functions with native code in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let me start by saying that I'm new to node.js and Promises.

I am using Bluebird to promisify some code in node.js 6.

The original code is written in C++ (project name: sapnwrfc). I have a working example using callbacks that goes like this:

```
con.Open(conParams, function(err) {                                             
  // some error handling                                                                         
  var func = con.Lookup('ZHELLO_RFC');                                          
  console.log(func.Invoke.toString());                                          
  func.Invoke({ }, function(err, result) {                                      
            console.log(result);                                                
  });                                                                           
});
```

The code above runs just fine, and the `toString()` output gives me `function Invoke() { [native code] }`. I promisified it using bluebird below:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var sapnwrfc = Promise.promisifyAll(require('sapnwrfc'));

// setup

con.OpenAsync(conParams).then(function(err) {
  // some error handling
  var hello = con.Lookup('ZHELLO_RFC');
  console.log(hello.Invoke.toString());
  return Promise.promisify(hello.Invoke)({ })
}).then(function(err, result) {
  // some error handling
  console.log(result);
});
```

When I run the snippet above, I get this in the output:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at tryCatcher (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:14:23)
    at /home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/sapOnly.js:27:44
    at tryCatcher (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
    at /home/phil/bc_workspace/MyProject/MyCode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeback.js:42:21
```

Am I missing something, or is native code just not supported?

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with the function using native code. It's just that it is a method that uses its `this` context.

Comment: one thing to note, functions passed to `.then` will only ever receive a single argument, so `.then(function(err, result)` is doomed to failure